# Ruby on rails routing to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to route a new method so that it can be called like so:

`method_users_path`

Users is a model, method is the new method i created which i want to link to.

Thanks, Muki

Comment: Please explain this question better. Where did you define this method?

Comment: The method was defined in the controller, i want to know what i have to add to call it using that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing with rails 3 you can have something like this in your routes.

```
resource :users do
    match "method", :on => :collection
end
```

this will create you method_users_path. Also you can use post/get instead of match if you want to be request type specific. See more about rails routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

**Update**

When you say `:collection`, your route  not will be object specific.
Collection action is for example the index, you dont have to pass any id for index.
For example `users_path`

Another is the `:member`, the member is object specific, so you have to pass an object id as a parameter, for example `edit_user_path(@user)` and you are passing user as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to add a custom method to your restful controller so for users, you would have something like `map.resources :users, :collection => {:something => :get}` and then you can call it in your view using `somthing_users_path`  (Rails2)e

Comment: @Muki dombesz just posted and explanation to your question, see above